# Performance impact on Module Vs Classes in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two sets of code and gona use to fetch result, I just want to know if both ways thing can be done.

```
//dataService.js

module.exports = {
getData: function(){// return data from some sync source}
}

const DataService = require(‘./dataService’);
console.log(DataService.getData());
```

Another way

```
//dataService.js
var DataService = Class DataService {
  getData (){ / return data from some sync source}
}
module.exports = DataService

const DataService = require(‘./dataService’);
console.log((new DataService()).getData());
```

please help me to understand, both code is fine in terms of performance and stander, when we put load with more than 1 Million request.

Comment: You're not really using the class as a class, so I don't see the point of using one (especially when you instantiate it for each request).

Answer (score 3):

I did a benchmark got the following results:

```
Class Data x 22,047,798 ops/sec ±0.88% (88 runs sampled)
Data as module x 31,695,587 ops/sec ±0.97% (89 runs sampled)
```

> **Fastest is Data as module**

*The result is pretty logical, you need to instantiate each time the class module with `new` also the memory consumption will be higher, new class is returning an instance with prototype chaining.*

The benchmark code:

```
const Benchmark = require('benchmark');

const moduleData = require('./modules/module-data');
const ClassData = require('./modules/class-data');

var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

// add tests 
suite.add('Class Data', function () {
  new ClassData().getData();
})
  .add('Data as module', function () {
    moduleData.getData();
  })
  // add listeners 
  .on('cycle', function (event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
  })
  .on('complete', function () {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
  })
  // run async 
  .run({ 'async': true });
```

Comment: What will happen if we create a class like this module.exports = new class Name {} ? Will it still have a performance impact or not? and if it still creates a new instance each time then what is the exact step to create a singleton class in nodejs?

Comment: So, in your tests you are instantiating the test class every time, whereas the module once ( with the definition of the module being its instantiation ) so theres that, and then in order to test you are testing using a class anyway.